# Word or phrase that describes when a fictitious character quotes real writing/speech etc

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, quotes

Is there a word or phrase to describe when a fictional character quotes/references something that exists in the real (our) 'universe' (but can also therefore exist in the fictional 'universe'). Either a piece of fiction, like Shakespeare or something real like  Martin Luther King Jr.'s I have a dream speech etc.

That reads as complex but it is a pretty simple idea really, some examples (and please note that it isn't limited to film and TV):

- in Star Trek "The Voyage Home" McCoy quotes Hamlet: *"Angels and ministers of grace defend us!".*
- in Star Trek "First Contact" they refer to Moby Dick - Lily compares Captain Picard's desire to kill the Borg to Captain Ahab and Moby Dick (also an extended metaphor in the film), and then Picard also quotes from it *"And he piled upon the whale's white hump the sum of all the rage and hate felt by his whole race. If his chest had been a cannon, he would have shot his heart upon it."*
- in the TV show Lost, Sawyer and Ben discuss Of Mice and Men by Steinbeck
- in Die Hard, Hans quotes Plutarch's Life of Alexander *"And when Alexander saw the breadth of his domain, he wept, for there were no more worlds to conquer."* (though if you search online there is debate about the accuracy of the quote)

Please note - I actually intended on using the word/phrase to describe how ineffective it can be, how it can break the illusion, to have fictional characters quoting etc.

Comment: Sometimes a quotation is just a quotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These references are called *allusions*. To allude to real literary works in a movie might contribute to *verisimilitude*, that is, these allusions might help the audience to forget that they're watching a fiction. Or they could be pretentious and heavy-handed, and remind the audience that they're watching a movie.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you @TRomano. If like me you rely on Wikipedia - [this narrative version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verisimilitude_%28narrative%29) not [this philosophical concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verisimilitude)

Comment: This answers OP's question about as well as Hot Licks' _quotation_. If The PM refers to Churchill, he is making an allusion. There is **no** hint that it is '**a fictitious character** quot[ing] real writing/speech etc'.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, @Edwin Ashworth.  The characters in the movies cited in OP's question are making allusions. They are fictitious characters. So there is more than a *hint* that a fictitious character is involved; that the person making the allusion is fictional is an explicit feature of the OP's question. Although in one of the examples, the movie is alluding; the characters are discussing.

Comment: You've answered 'Word or phrase that describes when a person quotes writing/speech etc' not specifically 'Word or phrase that describes when a fictitious character quotes real writing/speech etc'. You might as well say 'He's quoting ...' or 'He's referring to ...'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Are you implying that there is a more precise word for this  sort of thing? Is so, please advise.

Comment: I strongly suspect that there _isn't_ a decent answer, meaning specifically 'when a fictitious character quotes real writing/speech etc', which is what OP is asking for. In that case, one is best not to offer things like 'He's speaking' etc. Wikipedia refers to allusion to real-world events within a work of fiction as [Historical fiction  #Historical events as a backdrop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_fiction#Historical_events_as_a_backdrop).

Comment: I actually agree in part with you, Edwin. It seems there ought to be a word or phrase because it is quite a specific device and effect. Also please note my edit in the Q. I was actually originally trying to describe to someone how it can break the illusion of being immersed in fiction when a character poorly alludes etc. As @TRomano suggests at the end of the answer.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: who gives a FF what Wikipedia says?  And you have misread the OP's question, in any case. These are literary references, not "real world events". Weir's  *The Year of Living Dangerously* is set against a backdrop of real world events, for example.

Comment: I repeat 'I strongly suspect that there isn't a decent answer' to OP's question 'Is there a word or phrase that describes when a fictitious character quotes real writing/speech etc'. 'Quoting', 'referencing' and 'making allusions' give no sense of 'a fictitious character quoting real writing'. The claim that 'context makes this clear' does not redeem an unsatisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if these could be considered examples of [mimesis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Mimesis): "imitation of the real world, as by re-creating instances of human action and events or portraying objects found in nature".

However, I think this concept may be too broad to describe what the OP is looking for. Mimesis doesn't just mean fictional people quoting real authors or referencing actual events; it's everything the actors, and the work of fiction itself, deploy in order to pretend that what they're showing is real: the feigned emotions, the sets, the sound effects etc.

Comment: This is not what *mimesis* means, Patrick.